# pointerInput of Modifier takes no actions

Tags: android, kotlin, styling, android-jetpack-compose

I need a `Card()` Composable with a normal press and a long press functionality for a custom Card Composable.
The thing is `Card()` has its own value called `onClick = {}` and its working fine but has no option for a long press. So I researched if theres a way to handle it without styling my whole own Card Composable and there you go, the Modifier has an own function called `Modifier.pointerInput` which Ive tried but unfortunately it doesnt work.
Do I maybe use it wrong or is this functionality not available in `Card()`?

This is my implementation ([Adapted from the Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures)):

```kotlin
Card(
  modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
    detectTapGestures(
      onPress = { clickable() },
      onLongPress = { longClickable() }
  }
)
```

Am I maybe supposed to deactivate the `onClick` functionality of Card?

Comment: Nor sure what you are talking about, but `View`s should have `onLongClick()` which handles long presses.

Comment: It works for me. The problem must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @xjcl this is Jetpack Compose, not regular view system

Comment: I think its an import issue, you want to use this Card function https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Card(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,kotlin.Function0)

Comment: Also have a look at this one, I normally use this one: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).combinedClickable(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role,kotlin.String,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0)

Comment: Try to wrap your onClick callbacks with `rememberUpdatedState` e.g.: `val onLongClickState = rememberUpdatedState { onLongClick(entry) }` and use it with: `.pointerInput(Unit) { detectTapGestures(onLongPress = { onLongClickState.value.invoke() }) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a size modifier. This code works for me:

```
Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Magenta)
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures(
                    onPress = { Log.d("mlogs", "LoginScreen:  onPress") },
                    onLongPress = { Log.d("mlogs", "LoginScreen: onLongPress") })
            }
        , content = {}
    )
```